# Insert data from Excel to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I have a excel sheet, what I want is I want to upload the excel sheet record into the database table. But in that

1. `Emp_Code` is identity
2. `Qns` is Identity

I tried like below,

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dtExcel = new DataTable();
    dtExcel.Clear();
    string StrCount = String.Empty;
    string connString = "";
    HttpPostedFile File = FileUpload1.PostedFile;
    string strFileType = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName).ToLower();
    string path = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
    string Filename = path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1, path.Length - path.LastIndexOf("\\") - 1);
    path = Server.MapPath(@"~/Excels/" + "/" + Filename.ToString());

    File.SaveAs(path);
    if (strFileType.Trim() == ".xls")
    {
        connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
        // connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
    }
    else if (strFileType.Trim() == ".xlsx")
    {
        connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
    }
    string query = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet 1$]";
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
    conn.Close();
    if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
        conn.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
    OleDbDataAdapter daExcel = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    StringBuilder StrPubBldg = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(StrPubBldg);
    string ExcelfileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
    xw.WriteStartElement("DocumentElement");
    {
        xw.WriteStartElement("Emp_Eval_Proc_hdr");
        xw.WriteElementString("mkey", (0 + 1).ToString());
        xw.WriteElementString("Emp_Code", dtExcel.Rows[1][("Emp Code")].ToString());  //  Identity
        xw.WriteElementString("Emp_Name", dtExcel.Rows[2][("Emp Name")].ToString());
        xw.WriteElementString("Qns_No", dtExcel.Rows[3][("Qns No")].ToString()); //  Identity
        xw.WriteElementString("Self", dtExcel.Rows[0][("Self")].ToString());
        xw.WriteElementString("AS1", dtExcel.Rows[0][("AS1")].ToString());
  }
```

but getting error as

> There is no row at position 1.

How to do that ??

Comment: is it a repetitive task or just one time?

Comment: it will be a repetitive task..!! it will be updated if the record for some data exist

Comment: may be, If you excel sheet has only row then you get this error

Comment: @RachitPatel:I have many rows but the data is their for 3 columns for now. I just want to test whether the data is getting inserted or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dtExcel, you created a new DataTable then immediately clear it then attempt to access data. What you should do is follow this conceptual model. It does not have to be exact, the principle is to load data into the smallest container which for this is a DataTable, check if there are rows then iterate as needed.

Removed first code sample, replaced with new one as per request by poster

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;

namespace Example
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Create instance of this class,
    /// pass in file name and if excel sheet has headers e.g. YES or NO
    /// execute Work method, is currently incomplete
    /// </summary>
    public class StackOverFlowDemo
    {
        private string CreateConnectionString(string FileName, string Header)
        {
            OleDbConnectionStringBuilder Builder = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder();
            if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileName).ToUpper() == ".XLS")
            {
                Builder.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0";
                Builder.Add("Extended Properties", string.Format("Excel 8.0;IMEX=2;HDR={0};", Header));
            }
            else
            {
                Builder.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0";
                Builder.Add("Extended Properties", string.Format("Excel 12.0;IMEX=2;HDR={0};", Header));
            }

            Builder.DataSource = FileName;

            return Builder.ConnectionString;
        }
        public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
        public StackOverFlowDemo(string FileName, string Header)
        {
            ExcelTable = new DataTable();
            CreateConnectionString(FileName, Header);
            LoadData();
        }
        public DataTable ExcelTable { get; set; }
        public void LoadData()
        {
            using (OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection { ConnectionString = ConnectionString })
            {
                cn.Open();

                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand { CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet 1$]", Connection = cn })
                {
                    OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    ExcelTable.Load(dr);
                }
            }
        }
        public void Work()
        {
            StringBuilder StrPubBldg = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(StrPubBldg);
            // continue logic
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you modify a bit according to my code ? sorry for that